# Clear content insted of deleting row

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, scripting, duplicates

I have a range with data where I need a script to look for duplicates in the first column, and clear contents of the hole row in that range.

From this

[image]

To this

[image]

I've found this script, but it deletes the whole row. I need it to only clear content.

```
function ClearDuplicates() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("03");
  var rows = sheet.getLastRow();
  var firstColumn = sheet.getRange("A:A").getValues();
  for (var i = rows; i >= 2; i--) {
    if (firstColumn[i-1][0] == firstColumn[i-2][0]) {
    sheet.deleteRow(i);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please post what you want the output to look like, you show before and after, but please show a snapshot of exactly what you want the after to look like.

Comment: It's basically the same, but just clear content insted of delete row.

Comment: You want the entire row blank? Is there a reason you want to leave giant blank spaces?

Comment: As I wrote, "clear contents of the hole row in that range"
The range is here A1:C :-)

Comment: Are you still looking for the solution of your question?

Answer (score 1):

You need to retrieve the array data from column A and iterate through it comparing with the same array. When a match happens, apply clearContent() function [1] to clear the contents on that range (First get the range you want to clear in that row).

```
function ClearDuplicates() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var rows = sheet.getLastRow();
  var firstColumnValues = sheet.getRange("A1:A" + rows).getValues();

  for (var i = 0; i < firstColumnValues.length; i++) {
    var value = firstColumnValues[i][0];
    for (var j = 0; j < firstColumnValues.length; j++) {
      var comparisonValue = firstColumnValues[j][0];

      if ((value == comparisonValue) && (j>i)) {
        //You need to change the number of columns to which you need to clear the contents, in this case is 10
        sheet.getRange(j+1, 1, 1, 10).clearContent(); 
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[1] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#clearcontent

Answer (score 0):

You can just grab the range and clear it instead as seen below:

```
   sheet.getRange("R"+i+"C").clear();
```

Comment: @Hkroed try again.

Comment: No error from GS, but now it only clear the duplicate content from the first column, not the hole row...
What is the "R" and "C" ?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet.html#getRange(String)

Comment: @Hkroed it is clearing whatever rows your script was otherwise deleting... R just means row and C means column, you can use A1 notation if you want.

Comment: @Hkroed by the way I'm not sure I understand how your script is removing duplicates, it looks like you are just comparing the previous row, but your question was not how to remove duplicates it was how to clear a row instead of deleting it, if you need help with your remove duplicate formula you should ask a new question.

Comment: Hi!
Yes, the topic may not be specific.
But thanks for you help anyway :-)

Comment: @Hkroed you should mark this as the answer to "how to clear content instead of deleting row" and then ask another question if you can't get your remove duplicate function working properly.